# Command pg_dump not found?

Tags: 14.04, backup, postgresql

I was trying to make a backup in a server and I got the error:

```
pg_dump command not found
```

I thought that if you had postgres installed, it worked. What I have to do to install this command? I do not think that it is possible with `apt-get` or aptitude.

Comment: I believe pg_dump is part of the package `postgresql-client-x.x`, as well as a couple of other housekeeping utilities. Make sure you replace x.x by the proper version number for your server.

Comment: You need to install `postgresql-client-common` if you want it to be in the path. Either way it should be available in `/usr/lib/postgresql/YOUR_PG_VERSION/bin/pg_dump` (14.04)

Comment: Use [package.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=pg_dump) to find which package contains a given command/binary:

Comment: You've copied this from http://superuser.com/q/786363/167160. Please don't clone questions between sites, especially without linking between them. It wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

For 14.04 you can just install [postgresql-client](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postgresql-client) (as it depends on [postgresql-client-common](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postgresql-client-common)):

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
```

To quickly know which package contains a command/binary missing on your system, just use [package.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=pg_dump) (Search the contents of packages).

Comment: this also solves pg_restore not found error

Comment: You may need to add the postgresql repository as indicated here: https://askubuntu.com/a/633923/259828

Comment: On ArchLinux: `pacman -S postgresql`

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who get the same issue with PostgreSQL 10, you don't need to install additional packages; pg_dump is already there in postgres's `bin` directory. So you just need to append that bin path (e.g. `/opt/PostgreSQL/10/bin`) manually to the `PATH` environment variable.