# How install postgresql 9.4

Tags: postgresql

After trying `apt-get install postgresql-9.4`, updating, trying again etc etc. It seems I can't install it:

```
 Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.4'
```

I know there is a similar question in askubuntu but the answer there doesn't work either.

I need postgresql version 9.4 cause I'm doing a pg:backup from Heroku and I get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836312/postgresql-9-2-pg-dump-version-mismatch) error if I don't have 9.4.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How should we help you? You mention not even your Ubuntu version.

Comment: The official website describes steps for adding the postgresql repository, which will then allow you to download the postresql.



  More info : http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This command installs the recent version for your distribution:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

`postgresql-9.4` is available since Utopic.

<sub>[Source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=Postgres&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)</sub>

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) is a step by step guide to install Postgesql 9.4 for your Ubuntu (Utopic, Trusty, Precise, Lucid) version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE-pgdg main"
```

For trusty:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main"
```

To get your ubuntu version:

```
lsb_release -sc
```

Now import the public key and install:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

Comment: Answer improved, but what is your Ubuntu Version?

Comment: Thanks, I voted your answer up, I'll test it in a couple of hours. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Trusty.

Comment: @alejoss: As you seem to have forgotten to acept this answer: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 15):

Use the following commands (the command is capable of getting your Ubuntu version, No need of manual change):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4 pgadmin3
```

Source: [How to Install PostgreSQL 9.4 in Ubuntu / Linux Mint](http://technobytz.com/how-to-install-postgresql-9-4-in-ubuntu-linux-mint.html)

Comment: thanks, this worked nicely. +1 for making this dynamic with 'lsb_release -cs'

Answer (score 6):

You can install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

Version 9.3 will be installed for 14.04, 
9.4 for 14.10 and 15.04.

If you need 9.4 with Ubuntu 14.04, you can install it as described at [postgresql site](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install PostgreSQL 9.5 in Ubuntu in specific version like Ubuntu 14 then Follow the steps:

Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` and add a line for the repository :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main"> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists :

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5
```